# How do I remove duplicates in mongodb based on multiple array fields?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi this is an example of my structure.

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("12312341234cf123cc123456"),
    "internetMessageId" : "<1234@1234asdfasc.COM>",
    "ccRecipients" : [ 
        {
            "emailAddress" : {
                "name" : "Joe"
                "address" : "joe@gmail.com"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "emailAddress" : {
                "name" : "Marc",
                "address" : "marc@gmail.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "toRecipients" : [ 
        {
            "emailAddress" : {
                "name" : "Mary"
                "address" : "mary@gmail.com"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "emailAddress" : {
                "name" : "Frank",
                "address" : "frank@gmail.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "bccRecipients" : [],
    "from" : {
        "emailAddress" : {
            "name" : "Juan",
            "address" : "juan@gmail.com"
        }
    }
}
```

I have several duplicated documents as above and I want to keep only one of them. I understand that I should create a unique combination of columns from, internetMessadeId, toRecipients, ccRecipients, and bccRecipients but I'm struggling to put it all together.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please provide your expected output.

Comment: Imagine that I store 2 copies of the document specified in the question, which differ only in "_id" column. My goal is to keep only one of them and remove others.